# LINQ - EF - FROM or JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I use c#, linq and EF4.

I have two tables in my DataBase represented in my Conceptual Model:

DataBase Tables:

```
CmsContents
CmsCategories
CmsRelatedCategories (Pure Juction Table)
```

Entity Type:

```
CmsContent
CmsCategory
```

Entyt Set:

```
CmsContents
CmsCategories
```

I have some Navigational Properties:

```
for CmsContents --> CmsCategories --> Return Collection of Cms CmsCategory
for CmsCategories --> CmsContents --> Return Collection of Cms CmsContents
```

I need query Entity Framework to **retrive a list of Categories for a selected Content** not associated in the Junction table.

At the moment I use this code (note the two FROM):

```
var categories = from category in context.CmsCategories
                 from content in category.CmsContents
                 select category;
```

That Returns a list of all category not associated in the entire database and not to a specific Content.

I need show the list of Categories not associates with a *SPECIFIC Content*

- Any idea how to do it?
- May I do it with JOIN? (EF does not map directly he Pure Junction Table)

Could you please write me the LINQ query so I can have a clear picture.
Thanks fro your help.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you are planing on filtering "SPECIFIC Content"

Comment: Hi nix, I hope my question was clear enough, the problem is I'm not able to work on a specific Content. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
CmsCategories.Except(myContent.CmsCategories)
```

myContent is an instance of CmsContent, assuming you retrieved it before and you have lazy loading enabled.

Edit: a possible sample of code:

```
var myContent = context.CmsContents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
var contentCategories = myContent.CmsCategories;
var otherCategories = context.CmsCategories.Except(contentCategories);
foreach (var item in otherCategories)
{
//whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matteo, so where I can place the code you suggested me?

Comment: I also receive an error Unable to create a constant value of type 'WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsCategory'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: The code I posted is the query that will return you the collection of categories that don't belong to the specific product. You will place it wherever you need it to be, I don't really understand your last question. The error you posted is a rightful error but I can't possibly know why you're gettin it if you don't provide me some context to work on.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this wont work, he is looking for content that is does not have an associated category assigned.

Comment: This is an interpretation problem. He stated: "I need query Entity Framework to retrive a list of Categories for a selected Content not associated in the Junction table." I read it as "I want the list of categories that are not associated to a given content". Maybe the OP should clarify better what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes correct Matteo, as you sad it. The problem I'm not able to use your code, but it is my fault I'm pretty new at coding so for sure i'missing smt.... are you able to provide me a full example?

Comment: Thanks once again, now it is clear and I was able to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select from the `CmsCategories` and exclude anything that is *in* the associative table.

```
var query =
            context
                .CmsCategories
                .Except(context.CmsRelatedCategories.Select(x=>x.CmsCategory));
```